# using facebook, gmail, twitter to login to app

Tags: facebook, api

I'm making a video game that will be played on Windows (Desktop), Linux (Desktop), iOS, and Android. It's NOT a web based game. Instead of making people create an ID/PW specifically for my game I'd prefer to let them use their existing FB, G+, twitter, etc to login/create account. I'm not big into the social network side of things so is this an OK practice and if so where would I even start for FB, G+, & twitter API's to figure out how to do this?

I'm reading that OAuth is the way to go for client side applications. Does OAuth sit on top of OpenID or are they not related at all? Trying to read up on it but not getting that answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: [OpenID](http://openid.net/). And yes, I think in fact a lot of people would say it is a best practice.

Comment: Do you, or anyone else, know of a C++ or Lua api for Windows that gives me OpenID functionality? Most everything I'm finding is Java or .NET.