# Authenticate gmail/yahoo user in ios app via his email id & password

Tags: ios, authentication, gmail, yahoo

In my mobile app, I want to authenticate gmail/yahoo user via his email id & password to access my mobile app (I have done this with the Facebook). After lots of research, found repeated questions like [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238506/how-do-we-authenticate-users-in-mobile-apps-for-android-and-iphone), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104772/using-facebook-gmail-twitter-to-login-to-app) and got this reference as [Google api doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps).

I have gone through the reference site and its code but not understood which is the domain and where to send which request.

Is there any way to authenticate gmail/yahoo user via his email id & password? Please help.

Comment: Just a hint, Google and Yahoo (also Facebook) use OpenID. If you would like implement "Sign in with Google/Yahoo" then you probably need to use OpenID. This may help http://developer.yahoo.com/openid/